# Comparison between Group By technique of Python and SQL partition by

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I want to ask a conceptual question.

I have a table that looks like

```
UPC_CODE    A_PRICE     A_QTY    DATE       COMPANY_CODE    A_CAT
 1001        100.25       2     2021-05-06      1             PB
 1001        2122.75      10    2021-05-01      1             PB
 1002        212.75       5     2021-05-07      2             PT
 1002        3100.75      10    2021-05-01      2             PB
```

I want that for each UPC_CODE and COMPANY_CODE the latest data should be picked up.

To achieve this, I have SQL and Python

Using SQL:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPC_CODE, COMPANY_CODE ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
FROM yourTable)

SELECT UPC_CODE, A_PRICE, A_QTY, DATE, COMPANY_CODE, A_CAT
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Using Python:

```
df = df.groupby(['UPC_CODE','COMPANY_CODE']).\
     agg(Date = ('DATE','max'),A_PRICE = ('A_PRICE','first'),\
     A_QTY = ('A_QTY','first'),A_CAT = ('A_CAT','first').reset_index()
```

Ideally I should be getting the following resultant table:

```
UPC_CODE    A_PRICE     A_QTY    DATE       COMPANY_CODE    A_CAT
 1001        100.25       2     2021-05-06      1             PB
 1002        212.75       5     2021-05-07      2             PT
```

However, using SQL I am getting the above, but this is not the case for Python.

What I am missing out here?

Comment: @Vahram Daniyen : Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upc_code` and `date` columns might be used along with `rank(method='first',ascending = False)`, *eg. descending order while determining first rows* , applied `dataframe.groupby()` function after converting `date` column to **datetime** type in Python in order to filter out the corresponding rows with value = **1** for `df['rn']`

```py
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['rn']=df.groupby('upc_code')['date'].rank(method='first',ascending = False)
print(df[df['rn']==1])
```